# Duct connector for bathroom fan doesn't fit in the attic space. What are my options?

Tags: bathroom, ducts, exhaust-fan

I am in the process of removing an old bathroom fan and replacing it with a newer [Broan-Nutone](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-NuTone-ARN110LKVV-SurfaceShield-Exhaust-Vent-Fan-w-LED-and-Vyv-Antimicrobial-Virus-Killing-Light-110-CFM-ARN110LKVV/313274100) fan.  The new fan came with a [4" duct connector](https://imgur.com/a/zReTWm4), which will require a connector to attach to my 3" duct, but I digress.

The issue I'm running into is that about 2" away from the installation, there is a pipe running perpendicular to the joist.  Because of this, the duct connector included with the fan simply doesn't fit.  I've put in quite a bit of work for the installation of the fan, including cutting a larger opening in the ceiling, centering it in the ideal position, and have the wiring ready to go.  I really don't want to move the fan, both in terms of aesthetic, and also having to deal with patching up a ceiling.

Do I have any options here?  This is in a guest bathroom that is seldom used, and I contemplated just not hooking up any ducting and letting it vent into the attic, but I'd prefer not to run the risk of mold.

Perhaps not the best photo, but [this](https://imgur.com/a/dbOmA4h) is the best I could get of the pipe through the opening where that duct connector should go.

Comment: Is that flexible duct in your image for the exhaust fan? If so, then is there enough play in it to rotate your fan 180 degrees and still hook up to the flexible duct? The offending pipe looks like a plumbing vent. If it's ABS and there aren't any utility machines on your roof or in your attic, then that pipe is a vent for sure. Vents are the red-headed step children of the plumbing world, where you could cut out a section and replace it with a c-shaped work-around and nobody would ever be offended.

Comment: To be sure, are you implying rotating the fan enclosure 180 degrees?  I had thought about that, but then wasn’t sure how I’d mount it on the joist since the mounting holes only appear to be on one side.

Comment: Drill your own holes on the other side. Having the screws inside the enclosure is no big deal.

Comment: Or if you're desperate to use the mounting holes, you can add blocking to the joist on the other side until that surface works with your hole in the sheetrock.

Comment: Be careful about "drill your own mounting holes". There might be reinforcements in the fan housing on the side with the mounting holes that don't exist on other sides. Also, installing it _not_ in accordance with the instructions invalidates the UL Listing which could give you issues if there's ever an insurance claim. That said, it's 99.99% likely that the housing is designed to be mounted to a joist on any of the 4 sides because they don't know where you need the vent outlet to run.

Comment: Additionally, if that is a vent pipe, it can be easily rerouted. HOWEVER, you need to maintain proper slope in your new routing. Vent pipes are often open straight up on the roof which means rain/snow get in them. You need slope to ensure that water will properly drain to your sewer system and not puddle in the vent, blocking the vent and causing drainage problems elsewhere in the house.

Comment: if you are going to leave it open into the attic, instead consider duct taping a thick plastic bag around the back of the extractor, then attach the duct to the a hole in the bag. That will work far better than nothing and will look fine to your guests. You could use a plastic storage box too.